# Comparing decimal ignoring precision if it is zero

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, decimal

In my code I am tracking change in my object by comparing current and old values using reflection over properties. I have one field of type `decimal(5,2)` in the database.

So when I pass, say `12` to the database from front end it gets stored as `12.00`, this is fine. But if I try to save the object again with the value 12 the update tracker finds it different than the current value, so update tracker says

`12 != 12.00`

And so it records it as an update which actually is not because they are same values.

How can I check for the equivalence of such values?

**EDIT**

From update tracker I mean that I have written my own method `SaveChanges` in TemplateContext of EntityFramework which when called actually call the native `SaveChanges` method but before that it iterates through all the properties of the object using Reflection and tracks the change in the property and if there is a change then inserts in into one of my database tables to show the logs to the user of what all is changes and when.

So in that code I am checking the old value that is stored in the database and the new value that is provided by the UI.

So that property in my C# class is of type decimal and so I am not actually comparing int with decimal, I am checking decimal value with a decimal value.

So `12` is also stored in a `decimal` property and `12.00` is also stored in a `decimal` property

**Edit 2**

This is method that is tracking the change

```
public int SaveChanges(string personnelNo, string fullName, DateTime? now = null)
{
    var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
    now = now ?? DateTime.UtcNow;

    foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
    {
        var entityName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;
        var primaryKey = GetPrimaryKeyValue(change);

        foreach (var prop in change.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.Where(p=> skipUpdatesProperties.Any(s=> s==p) == false))
        {

          // below are the two lines which get original and current value
          // originalValue is coming from the database as 12.00
          // currentValue is coming from UI as 12
          // This is where it fails and says that the values are different 
          // I also tried removing ToString() also and comparing directly that also doesn't work
            var originalValue = change.OriginalValues[prop]?.ToString(); 
            var currentValue = change.CurrentValues[prop]?.ToString();
            if (originalValue != currentValue) //Only create a log if the value changes
            {
                //Create the Change Log
                var ut = new Model.UpdateTracker
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    TableName = entityName,
                    TableKey = primaryKey.ToString(),
                    FieldName = prop,
                    OldValue = originalValue,
                    NewValue = currentValue,
                    CreatedOn = now.Value,
                    CreatedBy = personnelNo,
                    CreatedByFullName = fullName
                };
                this.UpdateTrackers.Add(ut);
                this.Entry(ut).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough to provide any suggestion. How you are tracking those changes? post code for your so called *update tracker*

Comment: How are you performing the comparison? In SQL `12` as an `int` and `12.00` as a `decimal(5,2)` have the same value. `SELECT CASE CONVERT(int,12) WHEN CONVERT(decimal(5,2),12.00) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;` returns `1`, not `0`.

Comment: You compare strings, not decimals. `"12"` and `"12.00"` are different strings.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg - I mentioned there that I tried removing `ToString` method also and tried to check the values directly, that also doesn't work

Comment: @PawanNogariya: If `OriginalValues[prop]` and `CurrentValues[prop]` have `object` return value, then please also note that equality check by `==` and `!=` will use a reference comparison even if the boxed values are decimal. Have you tried to use `Equals`?

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg - Thanks Man!!!! You saved me! `object.Equals` method worked!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After detecting the real issue, adding as an answer, too:

If `OriginalValues[prop]` and `CurrentValues[prop]` have `object` return value, then please note that equality check by `==` and `!=` will use a reference comparison even if the boxed values are `decimal`s. Use `Equals` instead.